# _.findwhere doesn't work with ng-repeat on select options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have the following dropdown code

```html
<select data-role="listview" class="form-control" id="txtUserRole" name="Role" data-ng-model="AddEditUserCtrl.SelectedRoleId" required="required"
        data-ng-disabled="!($root.UserSchoolPermissions.indexOf('User.ChangeRole') > -1) && AddEditUserCtrl.isInEditMode" 
        data-ng-change="AddEditUserCtrl.roleChanged(AddEditUserCtrl.SelectedRoleId)"  
        data-ng-class="{'border-error': AddEditUserCtrl.userForm.Role.$invalid && AddEditUserCtrl.userForm.Role.$error.required  && (!AddEditUserCtrl.userForm.Role.$pristine || submitted)}">
            <option value="" selected class="text-muted">{{'Role' | translate}}</option>
            <option data-ng-repeat="option in AddEditUserCtrl.roles" value="{{option.RoleId}}" title="{{option.RoleName}}" data-ng-selected="{{AddEditUserCtrl.SelectedRoleId == option.RoleId}}">{{option.RoleName | translate}}</option>
</select>
```

what i am trying to do is getting the `AddEditUserCtrl.SelectedRoleId` from ng-model and pass it to ng-change function to get the role object using _.findwhere using the below JS code

```js
 AddEditUserCtrl.roleChanged = function (roleId) {
            
            var selectedrole = _.findWhere(AddEditUserCtrl.roles, {
                RoleId: roleId
            });
            AddEditUserCtrl.user.Role = selectedrole
            }
```

after debugging i find that `roleId` is passed right from the html and `AddEditUserCtrl.roles` array contains object that match the `roleId` but it doesn't work.

check the following screenshot for my debugging 
[image]
PS: i tried making the select tag using data-ng-options and it worked but i need it with data-neg-repeat on option tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your screenshot, it looks you are trying to compare a string and a number. `roleId` being passed into `findWhere()` looks to be a string, but the property `RoleId` you are attempting to match against is a number, that is why nothing is matching. Try the following, adding a [Unary Plus Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) to string `roleId` coming from the HTML to convert to a number:

```
var selectedrole = _.findWhere(AddEditUserCtrl.roles, {
  RoleId: +roleId
});
```

You could also use `Number(roleId)` or `parseInt(roleId, 10)` to convert from a string to a number.

```js
var roles = [
  { RoleId: 1, RoleName: "Teacher" },
  { RoleId: 2, RoleName: "Student" },
  { RoleId: 9, RoleName: "Foo" }
];

function roleChanged(roleId) {
  var selectedRole = _.findWhere(roles, {
    RoleId: +roleId
  });
  
  console.log(selectedRole);
}

roleChanged("9");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore.js"></script>
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: thank you, i didn't notice it !!
but why when i used data-ng-options it returned number and returned string with data-ng-repeat ?!